# my SDL_Renderer* seem to not work when I pass it into a function

Tags: c++, sdl-2

I have my main func:

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    int broad[40][20] = {0};
    SDL_Renderer* renderer = NULL;
    SDL_Window* window = NULL;
    srand(time(NULL));
    SDL_Event e;
    bool quit=false;
    if (!Init(renderer,window))
    {
        cout << "Can't INIT Window Screen. ";
        return 0;
    }
    else
    {
        if (!load_block(renderer))
        {
            cout << "Can't load BLOCK. ";
        }
        else
```

I create renderer in main than pass it in Init and load_block.
this is my load_block:

```
bool load_block(SDL_Renderer* renderer)
{
    bool success = true;
    color_block[RED] = loadTexture(renderer,"red_block.bmp");
    if (color_block[RED] == NULL)
    {
        cout << "Unable to render IMG. SDL Error: \n" << SDL_GetError();
        success = false;
    }
```

I continue pass my SDL_Renderer* variable into my loadTexture func:

```
SDL_Texture* loadTexture(SDL_Renderer* renderer,string path)
{
    SDL_Texture* newTexture = NULL;
    SDL_Surface* loadedSurface = SDL_LoadBMP(path.c_str());
    if (loadedSurface == NULL)
    {
        cout << "Unable to load image. Error: \n " << SDL_GetError();
    }
    else
    {
        //SDL_SetColorKey( loadedSurface, SDL_TRUE, SDL_MapRGB(loadedSurface->format, 0x00, 0xFF, 0xFF ) );
        newTexture = SDL_CreateTextureFromSurface(renderer,loadedSurface);
        if (newTexture == NULL)
            cout << "Unable to create texture from " << path << " Error: \n" << SDL_GetError();
        SDL_FreeSurface(loadedSurface);
    }
    return newTexture;
}
```

But it seem to not work. 
It return me the error that: invalid renderer ? 
what wrong with my renderer variable ? 
Can I fix it ? I don't want to create my image in main func, and extern renderer seem to not work too, btw I don't want to use a global variable.

[my console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ERdNB.png)

this is my function Init:

```
bool Init(SDL_Renderer* renderer, SDL_Window* window)
{
    bool success = true;
    window = SDL_CreateWindow("SDL Tetris", SDL_WINDOWPOS_UNDEFINED,SDL_WINDOWPOS_UNDEFINED,SCREEN_WIDTH,SCREEN_HEIGHT,SDL_WINDOW_SHOWN);
    if ( window == NULL )
    {
        cout << "Window could not be created. Error: \n" << SDL_GetError();
        success = false;
    }
    else
    {
        renderer = SDL_CreateRenderer(window,-1,SDL_RENDERER_ACCELERATED);
        if (renderer == NULL)
        {
            cout << "Renderer could not be created. Error: \n" << SDL_GetError();
            success = false;
        }
        else
        SDL_SetRenderDrawColor(renderer,0xFF,0xFF,0xFF,0xFF);
    }
    return success;
}
```

And I got nothing like "Renderer couldn't be created". So I think my renderer had been created successful.

Comment: What is the value of `renderer` in `main`'s scope after `Init`? I suspect it is `NULL` edit: In other words I suspect you only change `renderer` in `Init`'s scope and leave `main`'s version unchanged.

Comment: Show some or all of Init too, as that's where the issue is.

Comment: I suspect `Init` takes pointers by value.

Comment: I edited my question. I don't know but my Init() not seem to be a problem

Comment: @sockyone function takes copy of a value you passed to it. It can its own copy of a pointer, but no modification of this copy will be visible to calling side. Take a look at `SDL_CreateWindowAndRenderer` signature as an example of how it can be handled.